# Unable to join Azure Windows VM to an “Azure AD Domain Services” domain

Tags: entra-id, entra-domain-services

I am having difficulty joining an Azure Windows Server 2016 VM to an “Azure AD Domain Services” domain. I think the problem may be that I am not getting my credentials entered correctly when I get prompted  for the name and password of an account with permission to join the domain. I have referenced the following document to assist:  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/active-directory-ds-admin-guide-join-windows-vm-portal

Per this note in the document I have tried both the UPN and SAM account name format but I always get “the user name or password is incorrect”:

Tip - We recommend using the UPN format to specify credentials. If a user's UPN prefix is overly long (for example, joehasareallylongname), the SAMAccountName might be auto-generated. If multiple users have the same UPN prefix (for example, bob) in your Azure AD tenant, their SAMAccountName format might be auto-generated by the service. In these cases, the UPN format can be used reliably to log on to the domain.

Domain name is like: thisnamexxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com (14 characters prefix the “.onmicrosoft.com”)

User name is like: myname@whatever.com

When the credential dialog box comes up I have tried all of the following:

1)  Domain listed in box: thisnamexxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com    username: myname

2)  Domain listed in box: thisnamexxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com    username: myname@whatever.com

3)  No domain listed in box, UPN format: myname@thisnamexxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com

4)  No domain listed in box, UPN format: myname@whatever.com@thisnamexxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com

5)  No domain listed in box, SAM format: thisnamexxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com\myname

6)  No domain listed in box, SAM format: thisnamexxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com\myname@whatever.com

None of these work.... They all get a NetJoin 1326 error (the user name or password is incorrect)

- thisnamexxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com is listed as my default directory
- I have enabled password synchronization as these accounts are Azure AD only accounts.
- I am using an account that is in the AAD DC Administrators group
- I have verified and re-verified I am using the correct password....
- I have searched and read many answers to this question but can’t seem to find the needed solution

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I solved the problem:

When you look at your list of users in the Azure AD domain listing, the column on the far right lists the “source” of the account. I had 2 accounts in the “AAD DC Administrators” group.  One had a source of “Microsoft account” and the other a source of “external azure active directory.” It was these 2 accounts I had attempted to use to join the VM to the domain and could never get it to work. And yes, I went through the procedures to “enable password hash synchronization to your managed domain for cloud-only user accounts”.

What I then did was create a new user native to my Azure AD domain services domain, i.e source type of “Azure Active Directory” and added that user to the “AAD DC Administrators” group. I was then able to use these account credentials to get the VM joined to the domain. Several articles I read led me to believe that I should have been able to do this with the other accounts in the “AAD DC Administrators” group. However, it was only after using an account created in my native Azure AD domain services domain, that I was able to get this to work.